# Initialization of variable by another variable

Tags: declaration

We know that int `x = 1;` is considered initialization however does `int x = y;` considered initialization of the variable `x` if we initialized `y` before? For example:

```
int y = 1;
int x= y;
```

Comment: Please tell us in which language you're working.

Comment: Add a language tag to your post.